# Get the Cart shipping label and cost in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I need to display the shipping cost in other side of cart page.

I tried:

```
<?php
$current_shipping_cost = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
echo $current_shipping_cost;
?>
```

But print value nad don't title of shipping cost, because i use as title: "Express delivery with UPS 24/48 hours 4.90 euro"…

How can I get order shipping cost in woocommerce?

Answer (score 16):

To get and display the chosen shipping method label *(and other related data, if needed)* in cart page *(or in checkout page)*:

```
foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $method_id => $rate ){
    if( WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0] == $method_id ){
        $rate_label = $rate->label; // The shipping method label name
        $rate_cost_excl_tax = floatval($rate->cost); // The cost excluding tax
        // The taxes cost
        $rate_taxes = 0;
        foreach ($rate->taxes as $rate_tax)
            $rate_taxes += floatval($rate_tax);
        // The cost including tax
        $rate_cost_incl_tax = $rate_cost_excl_tax + $rate_taxes;

        echo '<p class="shipping-total">
            <strong class="label">'.$rate_label.': </strong>
            <span class="totals">'. WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total() .'</span>
        </p>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but what about taxes? get_cart_shipping_total() - this function include taxes, if not, why are code rate taxes?

Comment: @Marek (Other data is there if needed, just to show up)…

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.